# Show a row in a Tablix only once using a hidden expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, builder

I am currently working on a report in Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 2014. 
I have a tablix with data in it that is information that only needs to show once, but it is repeated for each new element in the tablix.

Is there any way possible to create a hidden expression that only allows it to show once and then sets hidden to true?

I have already tried using `RowNumbers` function with no success (I could be using it wrong)

```
=IIF(RowNumber("Tablix6")>1, true, false)
```

The result I am currently getting is that the item is not showing for any element in the tablix.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to remove duplicates in the query?

Comment: Also, do you have any header rows in the Tablix?  You might need to specify `>2` or better yet, remove the detail grouping.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add a snippet similiar to below in the Report Code of the RDL --> Report|Report Properties|Code.

```
Public _ShouldShow As Boolean = True

public Function ShouldShow() As Boolean
    Dim Result As Boolean = _ShouldShow
    _ShouldShow = Not _ShouldShow 
    return Result 
End Function
```

Then for the item on the report you want to show only once, reference the toggle function in the visibility property.

```
Hidden= !Code.ShouldShow()
```